# JSON validate extra parameter using schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to validate a json input through json schema. The positive case works for intended objects and properties. 
But I want to validate against extra objects, parameters which are not mentioned in the schema.

Basically fail the validation if garbage data detected in the json

Comment: Can you post some things that you've tried?

Comment: {
    "type":"object",
    "required":true,
    "properties":{
        "name": {
            "type":"object",
            "id": "build",
            "required":true,
            "properties":{
                "address": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "id": "job_name",
                    "required":true
                },
                "email": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "id": "publishing_area",
                    "required":true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
{"name":{"address":"x","email":"y","additional":"z"}}

Comment: I want to the request to be invalidated against the schema as "additional" is an extra key in that dictionary. Basically, strict dictionary keys

Comment: What are your schemas? What is your data? What are the expected results etc?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to only have a certain set of properties in JSON objects and refuse others:

- ensure the properties you want have a matching schema in either `properties` and `patternProperties`,
- define `additionalProperties` to `false`:

  ```
  {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": { "p": {}, "q": {} },
      "additionalProperties": false
  }
  ```

will only allow for properties `p` and `q` to exist in object instances.

Comment: Is it possible to, say, turn this on globally for a given schema?

Comment: @Hyperbole by default additional properties are allowed